# Linux Setup Machine for PHP/MySQL Development

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am an experienced ASP.NET developer. I would like to setup a virtual VMWare environment to start learning PHP.

What OS should I install? I am not aware of different versions of Linux.

Note: I know PHP can run on Windows, I want to give the Linux environment a chance.

Thank you & regards

Comment: The answers will probably be rather opinionated. If one tells you to use Ubuntu because it works so smoothly for him/her, the next suggests gentoo because of all the control and the next one wants you to use FreeBSD because linux is for pu..ppies, who's right? They all work.

Comment: Thanks all! Where can I download a Linux OS? Any links, would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what distribution you prefer. This site has links to a decent amount of distributions though: http://iso.linuxquestions.org/

Answer (score 1):

It is often best to choose an OS that replicates what you will be using in your production environment.

I have used Ubuntu server, and it is a breeze to install a webserver, php and mysql using apt-get. Others might prefer CentOS (or some other flavour of linux), but my opinion is that it is best to choose something that matches your production environment.

Answer (score 0):

It really does not matter on development side. Just pick dirstribuition of your choice.  Ubuntu has nicer frontend and could be more suitable for Windows emigrants,  while debian is more for backend guys.   However -  both have necesary toolsets to run and debugn PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can install and run Apache+PHP+MySQL in almost any distribution of Linux. Some distros can even have Apache+PHP+MySQL already built-in.